# Running php code on a separate server

Tags: php

I've had almost every solution to every problem I have encountered solved by this site without me having to sign up till now.

I would like to have a php script (function) that can be run by anybody on their site, where 3 variables are sent to my site and 1 new variable is returned.

The variables to send are: Username, Password and String.
The Username and Password sent will be checked against records in my SQL database and the string checked against a value.

1) Is this even possible? If so, how? I've seen bits on SSH2 but it looks rather confusing.

2) If it is possible, how secure would the data be while being transferred?

Comment: you can't have php call functions remotely like that. the php code you give "anybody" can do an http REQUEST to your server, but that's not calling a function... plus, if all you're doing is passing around a few vars, why do you need to get your users to install php just so they can run your function? it'll have to be an http request to your server anyways, so just tell them "hit url `http://example.com?key1=val1&key2=val2&etc...`"

Comment: ^ I would recommend sending the data using POST, over an SSL (https) connection

Comment: Check out REST APIs on google

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The user should be linked to the authorisation php app. Essentially user should be directed to this link:

> website.com/auth.php?user=username&pass=password&string=This%20is%20a%20string

You have to use urlencoding(%20) for the spaces, because the url can`t contain any spaces or special characters. And in the auth.php file you should use $_POST variable to get the values if you use a form, if you access the page directly you should use $_GET. I This is a sample variable from $_POST:

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
```

And this is a $_GET variable:

```
$username = $_GET['user'];
```

Post is used for sensative information